# Searching a string in multiple files in a directory in UNIX

Tags: unix, search

Can anyone help me on a command whi will help in Searching a string in multiple files in a directory in UNIX.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `man grep`

the man page of grep has all the info.

```
grep 'search_string'  directory/
```